# Getting my Lua file to update

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm making an addon for world of warcraft, and I'm to the point where my project is done, but it runs once and is done.

My objective is to make an interface on my screen that shows certain stats, and during combat you may get a proc of some sort and your stats will increase.

Right now my code creates the interface and shows base stats.

This is a function I wrote that I can use to update it correctly.

```
local function updateFunction()
    AgilityLine.text:SetText("Agility = ".. getRangedAgility())
    AttackPowerLine.text:SetText("AP = ".. getRangedAttackPower())
    CritLine.text:SetText("Crit = ".. getRangedCrit() .."%")
    MasteryLine.text:SetText("Mastery = ".. getRangedMastery())
    HasteLine.text:SetText("Haste = ".. getHaste() .."%")
end
```

I test it by making an in game command to run the function. How can I make the function run itself at a reasonable rate, maybe twice a second.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you update every 2s seconds :

local total = 0

```
local function onUpdate(self,elapsed)
    total = total + elapsed
    if total >= 2 then
        updateFunction()
        total = 0
    end
end

local f = CreateFrame("frame")
f:SetScript("OnUpdate", onUpdate)
```

Just using intern update system for addon =)

Source : http://wowprogramming.com/snippets/Create_a_mini-timer_using_OnUpdate_3

Comment: This is correct. Toward the other answer, this is how you add something to the game loop. I believe elapsed is in milliseconds not seconds however.

Comment: @Celess IIRC it's seconds with ms after the decimal, e.g. 1.5 for one and a half seconds or 0.1 for every tenth of a second

Answer (score -1):

you should add this function into the game loop function, maybe like timetick(); or you should write the timetick function yourself and call this updateFunction